# Refactor DataFrame to fill NaNs with data from other column, combine rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

Desire is input `DataFrame` reduced to `name` and `color` columns.  If `updated_name|color` has data, use it.  If `''` (`Nan` in true data set) then either use the value entered in `updated_name|color` column if it exists, and if not use the value in `original_name|color` column.

In real data set got about as far as the `DataFrame` below using:

```
mask = df['updated_name'].notnull() | df['updated_color'].notnull()
```

I am stuck on next steps.

An example `DataFrame` is worth a thousand words, minimum viable as follows:

Input `DataFrame`:

| sql_Key | original_name | original_color | updated_name | updated_color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Happy Bear | Red | Green Bear |  |
| 1 | Happy Bear | Red |  |  |
| 1 | Happy Bear | Red |  |  |
| 2 | Grumpy Bear | Blue |  |  |
| 2 | Grumpy Bear | Blue |  | Purple |
| 2 | Grumpy Bear | Blue |  |  |
| 3 | Sleepy Bear | Yellow | Energy Bear |  |
| 3 | Sleepy Bear | Yellow |  |  |
| 3 | Sleepy Bear | Yellow |  | Bright Yellow |

Desired Results:

| sql_Key | name | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Green Bear | Red |
| 2 | Grumpy Bear | Purple |
| 3 | Energy Bear | Bright Yellow |

Comment: can you paste `df.to_dict()` for minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, though I feel like it could be simpler: for each field in each group, get the first non-null "updated" value, otherwise get the first non-null "original" value.

```
g = df.groupby('sql_Key')

pd.concat(
    [
        g[f'updated_{v}'].first().fillna(g[f'original_{v}'].first()).rename(v)
        for v in ['name', 'color']],
    axis=1)
```

```
                name          color
sql_Key                            
1         Green Bear            Red
2        Grumpy Bear         Purple
3        Energy Bear  Bright Yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a dataframe making priority on `updated_name|color` columns for boolean check:

```
pd.DataFrame([(k, (g['updated_name'].dropna().unique() or g['original_name'].unique())[0], 
                  (g['updated_color'].dropna().unique() or g['original_color'].unique())[0]) 
                   for k, g in df.groupby('sql_Key')], columns=['sql_Key', 'name', 'color'])
```

---

```
   sql_Key          name          color
0        1    Green Bear            Red 
1        2   Grumpy Bear         Purple
2        3   Energy Bear  Bright Yellow
```